# Low Air Pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, air

Can we create low air pressure artificially in a system to make the wind blow towards the system from the higher normal air pressure in vicinity ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course we can.

One example would be in ventilation systems that utilize fans and blowers.  Supply ductwork for example would have blowers putting air into the ducts at higher pressure than atmosphere.  This high pressure "pushes" the air through the ducts towards the lower pressure surrounding air.

Something like exhaust ductwork does it in reverse.  The fan sucks air *out of* the ductwork, causing a low pressure which gets "pushed" by the higher pressure air of the surroundings through the ducts and out of the building.

So basically, yes, and this is is a crucial part of examining airflow, especially in closed buildings or large weather systems.

Comment: can we do this by making air warm in a system ? making the air warm in a system will make the air rise and will cause low air pressure in the system and then wind can flow from the higher air pressure around it towards the low air pressure in the system. can we make such a system or is there any example of that ?

Comment: @Alex Heating it up in a closed space should cause the pressure to increase (ideal gas law).  If you heated it up, with an opening for it to expand into, it will push itself into that space and maintain the same pressure.  You would need to heat it up with an opening so that it maintains pressure, then cool it down with the opening closed if you wanted it to get below atmospheric pressure.